# Single word for a response or answer to an 'assignment'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Yours truly is looking for a term that fits the general meaning, "the produced work in response to, or as an answer to, a task or assignment given by an actor (be it boss, client, professor)".

To provide more vivid context, see example below:

> **Assignment:** You are tasked with writing out something, then something else, and finally finish off by writing a conclusion.
>
> **[INSERT SINGLE WORD HERE]:** Something, then something else, and finally a conclusion.

In this case, it would be an elegant way to present and title out sections of a document wherein the assignment and [insert word here] can be presented at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, I'd say:
Submission.

The relevant definitions:

> 1.an act or instance of submitting
>   2.something submitted; a proposal, argument, etc
>   4.the act of referring a document, etc, for the consideration of someone
>  else
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/submission)
>
> 3.Present (a proposal, application, or other document) to a person or body for consideration or judgement. ‘the panel's report was submitted
>   to a parliamentary committee’
>  [Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/submit)

There may be more specific terms like:
tender - for a contract deal
report - for, well, a report
white paper - report identifying important issues on a topic and possible recommendations

Comment: This was *exactly* what I was looking for. My hat's off (and thanks) to you for your contribution – you hit the nail on the head.